# jquery limiting number of characters from .load

Tags: jquery, text, load

I'm loading in content from page with jquery load, I'm trying to limit the amount of characters it allows in the div, my function works, but only sometimes, I'm not sure why.

```
$('#violin_1_title').load('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html .violin:first .about .about_txt .about_summary h3:eq(1)', function() {

    $(".txt_limit").text($(this).text().substr(0, 450)+'...');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$('#violin_1_title').load('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html .violin:first .about .about_txt .about_summary h3:eq(1)', function(response) {

    $(".txt_limit").text(response.substr(0, 450)+'...');

});
```

This uses the parameter in the callback function which has the response data from the server.

Comment: so when I do this it doesn't load a fragment anymore, it literally loads the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting as response from the server would be HTML. So, in that case, you need to get the full content and then convert it to text / HTML output and from the output you need to apply the substring.

```
$('#violin_1_title').load('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html .violin:first .about .about_txt .about_summary h3:eq(1)', function(data) {

    $(".txt_limit").text(data.substr(0, 450)+'...');

});
```

If you are fine in doing with CSS, if it is a one line thing, you can do this way:

```
.txt_limit {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: my bad, it does work, but it has the same problem as above's solution, it posts literally the whole page, it no longer loads as a fragment.

Comment: See the second implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `.txt_limit` is dynamically loaded element then you should `.find()` it in existing parent:

```
$('#violin_1_title').find(".txt_limit").text().substr(0, 450)+'...';
```

or this:

```
$(".txt_limit","#violin_1_title").text().substr(0, 450)+'...';
```